# Attempting to use a search query with RecyclerView and firebase. When running the app, nothing appears in the recyclerview element

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Code for the search function. I have a button with a onclicklistener that runs this function and passes the edittext Search input as the parameter. The reason I am suspicious the error is in here is because I can't find consensus on the correct format for the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on youtube. I think I saw different versions of the FirebaseUI from video to video. I attempted to look at current documentation for the firebasedatabase functions but still couldn't get it working.

My app will run when I press search, but the recycle view never appears to be filled/populated. I'm wondering if I have it reading from the database incorrectly or maybe I have errors in how I am defining the adapter.

```
public void firebaseUserSearch(String search) {
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = ref.orderByChild("name").startAt(search).endAt(search + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserProfile> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserProfile>().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, UserProfile.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserProfile, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserProfile model) {

                holder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getAge(), model.getEmail());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        rvMenteeList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Code for my ViewHolder class

```
public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDetails(String userName, String bio, String img) {

            TextView user_name = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvListName);
            TextView user_bio = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvBio);
            ImageView profilePic = mView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic);

            user_name.setText(userName);
            user_bio.setText(bio);
            //Will add image link here
        }
    }
```

Code for my Model class

```
public class UserProfile {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String age;

    public UserProfile() {
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public UserProfile(String Name, String Email, String Age) {
        this.name = Name;
        this.email = Email;
        this.age = Age;
    }
}
```

My database is ordered in this hierarchy

```
thebloomapp-5426a
    DcehovJ6tRaHBdsau8IfjDcJfslny1
        age: "15"
        email: "trentjohnson505@gmail.com"
        name:  "kyle"
```

Comment: Have you tried to make the fields in your class private?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you run the code in a debugger and determine what exactly **is** happening (instead of only focusing on the final result that *isn't* happening). For example: if you put a breakpoint on the first line in `onCreateViewHolder` and run in the debugger, does it ever hit that breakpoint? Same for `onBindViewHolder`? And if it does, does the `model` contain the data for your user from the database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I ran my app through the debugger and everything in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, including onBindViewHolder & onCreateViewHolder is skipped over and never run. At least it never appeared to run in the debugger. I even created logs inside the onbind and oncreate methods and it never printed out these logs.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue, I forgot to add this line of code right above setting my adapter.
`firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();`
Without this line the adapter never listens for data from the database. The new changes in my search function look like this

```
public void firebaseUserSearch(String search) {
        ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = ref.orderByChild("name").startAt(search).endAt(search + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserProfile> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserProfile>().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, UserProfile.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserProfile, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserProfile model) {

                holder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getAge(), model.getEmail());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        rvMenteeList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```